# CSS3: How can I set middle DIV to maximum height?

Tags: css, height, scale

I want to use three `<div>` areas on my web page: *Header*, *Content* and *Footer*.

The *Footer* `<div>` is supposed to stick to the bottom of the web page.

The *Header* `<div>` is supposed to stick to the top of the page.

The *Content* `<div>` is supposed to fill the whole area in the middle of the page.

So this is the basic layout:

```
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

For the *Footer* to stay down the page I added

```
#footer
{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

For the *Content* `<div>` I'm using a background image, scaling exactly to the `div` element's dimensions:

```
#content
{
  background: url("Bilder/Bild.png") center contain no-repeat black;
}
```

Now I want the *Content* `<div>` to be exactly the remaining height of the ViewPort between *Header* and *Footer* without adding any JavaScript, no matter what content is later added to the *Content* `<div>`.

How can I do that in CSS3?

Answer (score 5):

If the size of `footer` and `header` is known, you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc). So assuming both take `100px` together, this should work:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#content {
  height: calc( 100% - 100px );
}
```

Be aware, though, that old browsers do not support this. Also have a look at the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility) for the prefixes that might be needed.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zEZh9/)

Comment: That's interesting! But so there isn't a value to explicitly set a block's height to "fit"? (Sorry for my late reply. I don't seem to get notifications on this thread.)

Comment: @AxD If you use percentage values on all three boxes, it would work as well. But i suppose, header and footer will have some fixed height, which from my knowledge only leaves this solution.

Comment: Looks great! However, if you add a border to the #content div, the bottom border doesn't seem to end where it should. No matter which box-sizing model I'm using on Firefox, the bottom border never is visible. Do you perhaps have an idea what should do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like this. it will allow you to keep your positions in a range of resolutions.

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 10%;
}

#content {
    position: fixed;
    height: 80%;
    top: 10%;
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 10%;
}
```

check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/57EGj/1/)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. So there's actually no property value to set the height to "fit" after all other height relevant blocks' sizes have been calculated? In HTML 4 there was the asterisk attribute value providing this feature.

Comment: I just tried your example. The only problem with it seems to be the width. If you put a border around the #content div, it'll just circumvent the text. Setting width: 100%, however, sets the right border to something far away. What width values would you suggest here?